# .NET Console Application Connection String Transformation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have just split my app into a web app and a console application webjob, I got the console application connected with my machines database through addition of ado.net and it mapped my models. However when I upload as a webjob to Azure I think it may still be trying to use the same database even though it as as web job for the application as it works for my local database on my local machine though not as a webjob.

Basically what I'm saying is how do I do the equivalent of the publish SQL settings and web config transformations of a web app in a console app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44752409/466245), maybe this is what you are looking for...

I was looking for an easy solution for Azure WebJobs project to transform App.config during build that works with Visual Studio and MSBuild on the server.

**1. Add an XML file for each configuration to the project.**

Typically you will have `Debug` and `Release` configurations so name your files `App.Debug.config` and `App.Release.config`. In my project, I created a configuration for each kind of environment, so you might want to experiment with that.

**2. Unload project and open .csproj file for editing**

Visual Studio allows you to edit **.csproj** files right in the editor—you just need to unload the project first. Then right-click on it and select **Edit <ProjectName>.csproj**.

**3. Bind App.*.config files to main App.config**

Find the project file section that contains all `App.config` and `App.*.config` references. You'll notice their build actions are set to `None`:

```
<None Include="App.config" />
<None Include="App.Debug.config" />
<None Include="App.Release.config" />
```

First, set build action for all of them to `Content`.
Next, make all *configuration-specific* files **dependant** on the main `App.config` so Visual Studio groups them like it does designer and code-behind files.

Replace XML above with the one below:

```
<Content Include="App.config" />
<Content Include="App.Debug.config" >
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="App.Release.config" >
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
```

**4. Activate transformations magic**

In the end of file after

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

and before final

```
</Project>
```

insert the following XML:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="exists('app.$(Configuration).config')">
    <!-- Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory -->
    <TransformXml Source="app.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="app.$(Configuration).config" />
    <!-- Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Now you can reload the project, build it and enjoy `App.config` transformations!

**FYI**

Make sure that your `App.*.config` files have the right setup like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
     <!--magic transformations here-->
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, might be dumb I have 4 .csproj files in both debug and release - CopyComplete, CoreCompileInputs, FileListAbsolute, ResolveAssemblyReference which one would I add this to?

Comment: Any and all that have multiple app.configs based on release/publish. Here I'll add a bit more info hopefully that will make it more clear.